# What is the difference between 'Wahi' and 'Ilham'?

Tags: terminology, revelation

Are these interchangeable terms?

Is there a way by which even non prophets can acquire information/communication from the unseen?

Comment: Just for reference: Even though the term "wahi" is used, the intention of the word might be "ilham", for instance 20:38 ("إِذْ أَوْحَيْنَا إِلَىٰ أُمِّكَ مَا يُوحَىٰ") or 28:7 , and for instance dhul qarnayn: qolna ya! 18:86 (قُلْنَا يَا ذَا الْقَرْنَيْنِ)

Answer (score 4):

### Linguistic meaning of wahy

In Arabic language both terms (al-Wahy الوحي and al-Ilhaam [الإلهام](http://www.almaany.com/en/dict/ar-en/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A5%D9%84%D9%87%D8%A7%D9%85/)) have a slight difference and can also be synonyms according the context.

Wahy [الوحي](http://www.almaany.com/en/dict/ar-en/%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%88%D8%AD%D9%8A/): inspiration, revelation etc.

> فالوحي لغة هو: الإشارة، والكتابة، والرسالة، والإلهام، و الكلام الخفي وكل ما ألقيته إلى غيرك .

In lissan al-'Arab لسان العرب you may find ilham counted among the synonyms of wahy which are: a sign, a letter, a message, an intuition (inspiration), a hidden speech/communication, one can even say it is any thing you say to an other person.

> يقال: وحيت إليه الكلام وأوحيت

It is said: وحيت إليه الكلام وأوحيت *wahaytu ilyahi al-Kalaama wa awhayto*
meaning: "I've talked to him using words or via a statement".
But literally it says: "I've inspired him or revealed him (with) some words or a statement".

Therefore in verse ([20:38](http://legacy.quran.com/20/38)) or ([28:7](http://legacy.quran.com/28/7)) the linguistic meaning is used to explain how the mother of Musa, was inspired to do what would save her son!

### Theological meaning of wahy

The meanings according to shari'a or the technical terms however make a clear  difference:
Wahy means: the order from Allah which was given to the Prophets

> التعليم الصادر من الله الوارد إلى الأنبياء،

so only Messengers or Prophets can receive wahy (revelation) according this definition.
There are two ways a revelation can be received:

> تعليم بواسطة ملك، وتعليم مباشر بلا واسطة ملك،

A teaching or instruction via an Angel or directly without the intermediation of any Angel.
Both can be in wakefulness or while sleeping by a good vision (see for example the long [hadith of 'Aisha](https://www.sunnah.com/bukhari/1/3)) or in a narration on the authority of ibn 'Abbas:

> **Nothing remains of the glad tidings of apostlehood (or prophethood), except good visions** which a Muslim sees or someone is made to see for him. ...
> ([Sahih Muslim](https://www.sunnah.com/muslim/4/236), but it also appears with a slightly different wording or narrator chain in other hadith collections such as sahih al-Bukhari, al-Muwatta' and sunan an-Nasa'i)

Note that the instruction via an intermediate has three known ways:

- That the Prophet sees the Angel in his real form or appearance (rare)
- That the Prophet sees the Angel in a human appearance
- That the Prophet fail to see the Angel, but hears some sounds etc.

### On the meaning of ilham

There are different definitions, what ilham might mean:
One of them is doing or saying (or being guided to do or say) the right  thing without being a Prophet.
Ilham is based on the hadith saying:

> "Amongst the people preceding you there used to be 'Muhaddithun' (i.e. persons who can guess things that come true later on, as if those persons have been inspired by a divine power), and if there are any such persons amongst my followers, it is `Umar bin Al-Khattab." (sahih [al-Bukhari](https://www.sunnah.com/bukhari/60/136) and sahih [Muslim)](https://www.sunnah.com/muslim/44/34) with a different wording)

Arabic sources (islamweb [#39071](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/39071) and [#72203](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/72203))