# What exactly is a 'Wahy' in Islam?

Tags: quran, hadith, terminology

I understand that in Islamic school of thought, it is said to be revelation of God's message to His chosen people like Prophets, Messengers *(and according to some folks also the pious and righteous slaves of God - **Ilham**)*.

**But how is it exactly delivered? Do we have any Sahih Hadiths?**

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wahy), I read this:

> " Islamic scholars have described three ways in which God's revelation
>   can reach His chosen individuals, especially prophets. An inspired
>   message – not a word but an idea – can enter the heart of the chosen
>   individuals either in the state of consciousness or in dream.[3] The
>   second mode, it is said, is the word heard by the person spoken to,
>   like, from behind a veil. In the third mode, the revelation is sent
>   from God through archangels like Gabriel and is delivered to the
>   prophets. It is the highest form of revelation, and Muslims believe
>   the whole Quran was revealed in this mode"

and

> "The common mode was that Muhammad would hear sound like "the ringing
>   of a bell" after which he found the message committed to his memory.
>   Sometimes, the arch angel would come in human shape, most often of
>   Dahya al-Kalbi. In two cases, Gabriel appeared in his real form. Once,
>   on the night of Miraj, Muhammad is believed to have had a direct
>   conversation with God. In the fifth mode, Gabriel would let the
>   revelation enter into Muhammad’s heart."

Comment: Relevant post [What is the difference between "Wahi" and "Ilham"?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/39805/what-is-the-difference-between-wahi-and-ilham)