# If i tell my dreams everyone can it harm me?

Tags: dream

Assalamu alaikum.my ques is:when i see some dreams and i dont get their meanings. can i share it to others?like my family members or relatives or someone else whom i trust.if they interpreted differently about my dreams can my dreams meaning be change?can it harm me?Some scholars have said that if I tell a lot of people about my dreams, my dreams will be turned upside down. Is it really possible?If I tell people about my dream without knowing it, will it hurt me or will it change the meaning of my dream?

Comment: I think this is relevant https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/48777/13438

Answer (score 2):

If it is a good dream, you should thank Allah, and it can be shared with relatives or friends (as you wish).

But in case, if it is a bad dream (nightmare), it is not good to share with anyone, and should seek refuge from Allah.

Ref:

*Narrated Abu Sa`id Al-Khudri:
I heard Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) saying, "If anyone of you saw a dream which he liked, then that was from Allah, and he should thank Allah for it and tell it to others; but if he saw something else, i.e, a dream which he did not like, then that is from Satan and he should seek refuge with Allah from it and should not tell it to anybody for it will not harm him."*

*Sahih al-Bukhari 7045*

Answer (score -1):

Never ever share dreams. Never look for meanings in dreams,
as they can be from Satan and can cause a lot of confusion, pain, sadness and even loss of imaan.
We were told by the Prophet Muhammad sallallahu alayhi wa sallam to never ever share dreams to anybody.

Comment: You said ''We were told by the Prophet Muhammad sallallahu alayhi wa sallam to never ever share dreams to anybody.'' Please provide the evidence for that. And what about this [hadith](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:7045)? Your answer is not fully correct.